# Using Python's `re` module to set all characters lowercase

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the re library to normalize some text. One of the things I want to do is replace all uppercase letters in a string with their lower case equivalents. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: FWIW, the re module is leading you astray here: [ask about the problem, rather than the attempted solution.](http://tinyurl.com/meta-xy).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> s = "AbcD"
>>> s.lower()
'abcd'
```

There is also a swapcase method if you want that.

See: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Comment: thanks. maybe you should edit it to str = str.lower() though.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to change the original string, then of course you're right - str.lower() alone does not change the original string.

Comment: @Nux: He's right that your example is confusing.  Your last line was 'str' (bad example variable choice, given the builtin str type), and the result of that line is *not* 'abcd'.  I've edited it to a simple python repl session instead.

Comment: @Roger Pate: OK, using `str` might be confusing, but still it would work and the result of `str.lower()` in my original example *is* 'abcd'.

Comment: @Nux: Yes, but your original last line, right above where you gave the result, was str, *not* str.lower().  That's all I was pointing out and what I believe alphomega was pointing out.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. OK, my bad :-). Though the console would show one what I meant ;-).

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use RegEx, you can do this:

```py
import re
def swapcase(s):
  def changecase(m):
    if m.group("lower"):
      return m.group("lower").upper()
    elif m.group("upper"):
      return m.group("upper").lower()
    else:
      return m.group(0)
  return re.sub("(?P<lower>[a-z])|(?P<upper>[A-Z])", changecase, s)
print(swapcase(input()))
```

## EDIT

If you want all lowercase text, try this:

```
def lower(s):
  import re
  return re.sub("[A-Z]", str.lower, s)
```

(Note: the `re` module is not the best choice here. Use `string.lower`.)

Comment: `swap` is coupled too mush with the outside--requires specific named groups to be made in the regex. I would recommend putting the `re.sub` in the function.

Comment: There is a (much) simpler way, but I tried to make it more human-readable.

Comment: I understand this, but that doesn't change the fact that the function is highly coupled to how the regex string is structured. As the user wants to operate on strings, the `re.sub` would benefit from being placed in `swap`, or remove the function altogether.

Comment: I see. Will change.

Comment: How is this complex code better than accepted answer?

Comment: The asker wanted RegEx, so I made a solution in RegEx in case the asker finds it better.